# Java- "Circular" selection in JTextPane?

Tags: java, string, swing

I've been working on a GUI to handle DNA sequences. Most of the molecules will be [plasmids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plasmid), which are circular forms of DNA. I can get a sequence as a string and display it in a JTextPane, but I'm not sure how to handle cases where the user might want to select a section of the sequence that crosses from the end to the beginning of the sequence. One thing I've considered is displaying the sequence twice, so you can select the last part of the first section and the first part of the last section, then overwriting some function so that copying the text will put the correct sequence on the clipboard instead of the string that was actually selected. (I'll have to do that anyway, I'm displaying the forward and reverse strands of the DNA, then a blank line, so that 1 "line" of actual sequence becomes 3 lines of text.

Is there some trick to circular strings that I just don't know about?

Comment: Use a single `JTextPane` for each sequence, use a `VerticalLayout` or `GridBagLayout` and add these to a `JPanel` and wrap the `JPanel` in a `JScrollPane`

Comment: Which component are you using? If you use one of the standard components such as JTable or JList you would just need to set your own custom selection model. Unless Swing components are buggy and won't handle selections like that, which is quite possible.

Comment: @ATrubka Currently, I am using JTextPane to display the DNA sequence. I plan on implementing a JTree to display the features in the sequence and allow some selection. I am still re-learning swing while trying to focus on my research. I just moved to a new lab that hasn't purchased any DNA software, thought I'd try to write my own. Haven't used Swing in about 3 years, and definitely nothing this advanced.

Comment: Sounds like an interesting project. I wish I could do something like that. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you know how other programs handle the selection of pieces of circular DNA? You might be able to get some inspiration from other software, like alignment viewers (supporting circular DNA) in this list on Wikipedia: [en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_alignment_visualization_software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_alignment_visualization_software).

I think it would be wise to decide on how you want the GUI to work first, and then start working on your code. Otherwise you risk wasting a lot of time on implementing ideas that you end up not using.

You could even consider offering both a circular and a linear view on the same sequencing data, as this screenshot from the [CLC Sequence Viewer](http://www.clcbio.com/products/clc-sequence-viewer) shows:

[image: Screenshot of CLC Sequence Viewer]

Comment: That design is very similar to what I'm trying to do. I'll take a look at that list and see if I can get a look at any of the code. This is a slow project because it's not my top priority.

Comment: CLC Sequence Viewer shown above appears to be freeware but closed source. There is also a tool called Unipro UGENE that seems to have similar functionality (see for example this screenshot from a forum discussion: http://ugene.net/yabbfiles/Attachments/circ.jpg). UGENE is open source and written in C++; you can download the code here: http://ugene.net/download.html. Good luck with your project!

Comment: I gave up trying to use a JTextPanel and went with a normal JPanel, and drew the text on using the graphics functions. I was able to set up custom selections that are shown as rectangles drawn on the text, and a mouse listener so you could drag the selection boundaries around. Because the selections aren't based on normal text selection, it was easy to get them to cross the end of the plasmid. It also means a user could keep several portions selected at a time, allowing them to easily keep track of multiple sequences.

Comment: Great to hear you're able to create a solution. Perhaps it's a good idea to share (some of) your code here for people that have similar questions in the future?

Comment: Maybe eventually. The code is messy and not well commented, and is honestly mostly kludged together. The new problem is getting the genes and other features to draw ok. I can make rectangles like the yellow ones in your image, but they overlap. I just haven't been able to wrap my head around how to sort the rectangles out and spread them out to avoid overlap.